# Cannot add notification endpoints for Google APIs project

Tags: amazon-ec2, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have an application where I use OAuth2 to grab some info from a users spreadsheet in Google Drive. I have just completed the OAuth2 procedure, which I thought was the challenging part since there are no OAuth2 libraries for xquery, but now I am running into another problem.

I send a GET request to the Google Drive SDK, which I have turned ON in the Google API Console, and get the following output:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

I have found this question which seems to be the cause of my error :[Google API returning Access Not Configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348689/google-api-returning-access-not-configured) but I am unable to complete the solution to my problem which is to " Visit code.google.com/apis/console. First, make sure the service you want is enabled under "Services". Then go to "API Access" and specify your calling domains or IP addresses." When I try to add my domain to the notification endpoints, it doesn't do it.

In addition, I see that it says "Allows webhook notifications to be sent to external domains that are owned by the user. Google verifies that the user does in fact own each of the listed domains via Webmaster Tools" in the box where you add said endpoints. Since I am on an Amazon EC2 instance I am not sure that I will be able to do that. I really hope the fact that I am on an Amazon server is not stopping me from making my app.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable Drive SDK **and Drive API** in the API console.

Comment: So simple how could I miss :/