# AngularJS and Cloud Endpoints on App Engine

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have been using App Engine since last three years and recently started exploring AngularJS and Cloud Endpoints for creating web apps.

I started with [this](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/angularjs-cloud-endpoints-recipe-for-building-modern-web-applications) recipe given on Google developer's website and facing following problems since last three days. I am using Eclipse with GAE plugin - App Engine SDK 1.8.9. Used the plugin for generating the APIs.

1. Why it stops working on localhost when it was running fine just a few minutes ago? I get proxy html error now and then. Situation is like - sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't!!
2. Why the same code when uploaded on GAE does not work at all (no data fetching or adding ) though things are working absolutely fine in API explorer?

Not posting my code since I am using the same code given in the above recipe.

**My question is : why this surprising behavior - no consistency? Am I missing anything?**

**SOLVED:
We have to use https and not http. Working fine for me now.**

Comment: check the api key if you set one. Might be the similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590652/access-not-configured-when-accessing-google-cloud-endpoints-from-web-app/20955319?noredirect=1#20955319

Comment: @extraeee - I do not have any API key added in the code.