# How to get Google Apps marketplace notification

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-apps-marketplace

I've created a new marketplace app and installed it on my domain. I'm trying to use the appsmarket api to get a list of domains which installed my app, with the following code:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(CLIENT_ID, PRIVATE_KEY, SCOPE)  
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build(serviceName='appsmarket', version='v2', http=http)
lists = service.licenseNotification().list(
  applicationId=APP_ID, timestamp=0, max_results=10).execute(http=http)
```

And i get the following error:

```
apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/licenseNotification/<APP_ID>?max-results=10&timestamp=0&alt=json returned "Access Not Configured">
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14373366/1795244) I should register my server's ip with google, but I didn't find where to do it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

There are two services with similar names in the Google Cloud Console (or the old API Console):

- Google Apps Marketplace SDK
- Google Apps Marketplace API

**The second one** has to be enabled for the licensing API to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
It's surprisingly hidden. 
Visit code.google.com/apis/console. 
First, make sure the service you want is enabled under "Services". 
Then go to "API Access" and specify your calling domains or IP addresses.
```

From the comments of the link you gave above

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read this comment before posting the question. (a) What is the service for `appsmarket`? if it's 'Google Apps Marketplace SDK ' it's already enabled, and (b) I didn't find the place to specify an IP address. There is only the 'Notification Endpoints' section in which I can only specify domains (and I'm not even sure that this is what we look for..)

Comment: Found it! It is 'Google Apps Marketplace API' and not 'Google Apps Marketplace SDK'

Comment: @Tzach the easiest way to do it is when you go to `code.google.com/apis/console` it gives you the option to go to the old console (not the new cloud console) chose that option in the yellow toast and then follow the instrucitons