# Determine if a google user's domain has my marketplace app installed

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

When a user logs in, I want to check if their domain has my Marketplace app installed.  It looks like this should in theory be possible with the [Marketplace License API endpoints](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/).

However, whenever I try to use the "Try it now" feature for the [Customer License](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/customerLicense), [User License](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/userLicense) or [License Notification](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/licenseNotification/list) endpoints, I always get a 403 Forbidden with the message "Not authorized to access the application ID".

For example, if I try to query the [LicenseNotification](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/licenseNotification/list) endpoint, I do the following:

Click on the Authorize toggle and click "Authorize" to authorize that scope for my logged-in user (which is the Google Apps Admin account which owns the application, btw).

For `applicationId`, I then enter the 12-digit "App Id" field from the Google Apps Marketplace SDK settings in the old developers console (Also known as Project Number from the new developers console app overview page).

When I click Execute I get the 403 "Not authorized to access the application ID".  I have also tried using my Project Id (i.e. "my-app" from the Developers Console Overview page) in place of the Project Number/App Id, and get the same response.

Am I missing something here?

Alternatively, if someone knows of another way for the owner of a GAM App to query a list of domains which have it installed, that would be an ideal solution for me as well - I couldn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, read some more and figured this out at last.

What I was missing was the fact that the authentication for the Licensing endpoints requires you to use a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/console/help/?csw=1#service_accounts), not a regular user account.  Which makes sense why the "Try it Now" feature on the documentation pages didn't work at all.

Unfortunately, we use PHP and the [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) does NOT yet have services for the Licensing APIs.  However, the client project does show [an example](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php) of using a service account instead of the normal user OAuth2 flow.

I used this example and stole a little bit of the source code from [Resource.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Resource.php)'s  `call` method to call the [Customer License endpoint](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/customerLicense) to check to see if a domain has our app installed or not:

```
$privateKey = file_get_contents('path/to/private-key.p12');
$serviceAccountName = '12345-j@developer.gserviceaccount.com';

$cred = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $serviceAccountName,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license'),
    $privateKey
);
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Apps_Marketplace_Licensing_Check');
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}


$url = \Google_Http_REST::createRequestUri(
    'appsmarket/v2/',
    'customerLicense/{appId}/{customerId}', [
        'appId' => ['location' => 'path', 'type' => 'string', 'value' => $appId], 
        'customerId' => ['location' => 'path', 'type' => 'string', 'value' => $domain]
    ]
);

$httpRequest = new \Google_Http_Request($url, 'GET');
$httpRequest->setBaseComponent($client->getBasePath());
$httpRequest = $client->getAuth()->sign($httpRequest);

/* returns JSON array */
$result = $client->execute($httpRequest);
$isDomainInstalled = ($result && isset($result['state']) && $result['state'] == 'ACTIVE');
```

Hopefully the folks over at the google-api-php-client project will eventually add a true service for these endpoints, but for now this workaround isn't too terribly painful.

Comment: Did you have to authorize the service account somehow? I still get this annoying error. Thanks.

Comment: Man, it has been so long, I can no longer remember. Hope you get it figured out!

Comment: I kept getting 403: Forbidden. As per this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20786740/126183) what finally worked for me was in the developer console, to also add the Marketplace API, not just the Marketplace SDK

Answer (score 0):

The licensing API may help you to obtain the information you need https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/v2/developers_guide

Comment: Yes, this is the customer/user license endpoints I link to in my question.  However, as I mentioned, when I try to query this API from their API Explorer feature on the page, I keep getting a 403.  

Also, sadly it seems that the google-api-php-client project is missing these endpoints entirely. :(