# Get "Not authorized to access the application ID" after using Google Apps Marketplace API

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-apps-marketplace

I have a web app and trying to find out which users in google domain have installed my app. I've tried to use code from here: [Determine if a google user's domain has my marketplace app installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206496/determine-if-a-google-users-domain-has-my-marketplace-app-installed), but it doesn't works. I am still getting error "(403) Not authorized to access the application ID" in response.

Code:

```
            $private_key = file_get_contents('path_to_p.12_key');
            $service_account_name = '{service_acc_name}'; // name from developers console

            $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($service_account_name, array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license'), $private_key);

            $client = new Google_Client();
            $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

            $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/licenseNotification/{appID}";

            $httpRequest = new Google_Http_Request($url, 'GET');
            $httpRequest->setBaseComponent($client->getBasePath());
            $httpRequest = $client->getAuth()->sign($httpRequest);

            try
            {
                    $result = $client->execute($httpRequest);
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
            }
```

I've also added https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license scope in project settings in developers console.

I can't get what's wrong.

Comment: did you grant the service account permission in appsmarket place to access the data?

Comment: Do you mean permissions in developers console? In console that service account has permissions "Can edit"

Comment: The service account dosent have access to anything you don't give it access to.  If you are trying to read from Apps Marketplace you need to give it permission in spps marketplace.   Million Dollar question is can you grant another user permission to see your data

Comment: Going through steps in block "Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account" from here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount I've also given permissions to service account in admin console of my test domain. That's all. Maybe I misunderstand what kind of permissions you talking about but I doesn't saw anywhere anything else.

Comment: Scopes define the permissions that your application needs.   You should only request the scopes that you need.  Normally you only request the scope you need but in the case of a service account its safe just to request full access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've solved it. You must add all scopes to your service account object that used by your app (not just that scopes you are really want to use by service account):

```
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($service_account_name, array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license'), $private_key);
```

Comment: I can confirm that this is indeed not needed - you only need the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license`.  As per this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20786740/126183) what actually worked for me was in the developer console, to also add the Marketplace API, not just the Marketplace SDK